# Concat with if in angular (how to use sequential request with conditions )

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an event which call 3 http observable. order of these request is important to me. so I have to use concat from rxjs. for example with the first request I got the data and fill my local variable values with that, then I want to check if the result of one of those local variable is true then send next request.

Something like that:

```
onMyEvent(e) {
    let isRoundingAdditionIsRequiered = false;
    let ishavePeriodicalDiscount = false;

    const api = 'api/Sales/SaleTemplate/' + e;
    const firstApiGet = this.dataSourceService.generateCustomApiDataList(
      'sales',
      'SaleTemplate',
      api
    ).dataList$;
    const secondApi= 'api/Sales/Addition/List?$filter=AdditionCode eq "4"'
    const secondApiGet= this.dataSourceService.generateCustomApiDataList(
      'sales',
      'SaleTemplate',
      api
    ).dataList$;
    const postApi = 'api/Sales/Contract/CalculateAllRowPrices/';
    const calculatePrice = this.dataSourceService.generateCustomApiPost
        ('sales', 'Contract', postApi, this.entity).dataList$;
}
```

Now by the result of `firstApiGet` I want to set `isRoundingAdditionIsRequiered` to  `true`. like this:

```
firstApiGet.subscribe(data => { if (data.RoundingAdditionIsRequiered) {isRoundingAdditionIsRequiered =true} });
```

then check it for next request:

```
if (isRoundingAdditionIsRequiered ) {
    secondApi.subscribe(data => {// codes here ...})
}
// and other codes ...
```

This is not work sequential so I have to use concat operator.

Something like

```
concat(firstApiGet,secondApiGet,postApi).subscribe(data=>{//...})
```

So what is the code?

Comment: You might want to try `combineLatest` or `forkJoin` instead of contact, your code should look like this `combineLatest([firstApiGet, secondApiGet, postApi]).pipe(....).subscribe({ next: ([first, second, third]) => { if (data.RoundingAdditionIsRequiered) {isRoundingAdditionIsRequiered =true} })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `switchMap` operator.

```
onMyEvent(e) {
  let isRoundingAdditionIsRequiered = false;
  let ishavePeriodicalDiscount = false;
  const api = 'api/Sales/SaleTemplate/' + e;
  const firstApiGet = this.dataSourceService.generateCustomApiDataList(
       'sales', 'SaleTemplate', api ).dataList$;
  const secondApi= 'api/Sales/Addition/List?$filter=AdditionCode eq "4"'
  const secondApiGet= this.dataSourceService.generateCustomApiDataList(
       'sales', 'SaleTemplate', api ).dataList$;
  const postApi = 'api/Sales/Contract/CalculateAllRowPrices/';
  const calculatePrice= this.dataSourceService.generateCustomApiPost(
       'sales','Contract',postApi,this.entity).dataList$;
  }
  firstApiGet.pipe(
     switchMap( data => {
        isRoundingAdditionIsRequiered = data.RoundingAdditionIsRequiered;
        return isRoundingAdditionIsRequiered ? secondApiGet : of( undefined );
     ),
     switchMap( () => calculatePrice )
  ).subscribe();
}
```

Comment: wow! I know by switch map we can unsubscribe from first request don't I?, so the order should work. let me try it then vote to your Idea

Comment: dear @Raid I want to check if isRoundingAdditionIsRequiered  ===true then secondApiGet send. by this even if  isRoundingAdditionIsRequiered   === false again secondApiGet  will send.

Comment: What should happen if isRoundingAdditionIsRequiered === false?

Comment: only firstApiGet and calculatePrice should be subscribed

Comment: it seems a perfect Idea, let me try it. by the way you are awesome ;)

Comment: @AliEshghi RxJS's `EMPTY` is a better fit than `of(undefined)`. You can also use filter to avoid the issue alltogether `filter(data => data.RoundingAdditionIsRequiered)`